# What is practical implication of Bandwidth delay product?

Tags: computer-networks, network-flow, network-topology, tcp

It's given that the bandwidth-delay product defines the number of bits that can fill the link; while the sender can send (1+(2 * Bandwidth * Delay)) units before getting acknowledged for the first unit. Can anyone help me to realize the practical implication the phenomenon of filling the link will imply? What can be the specific cases where (Bandwidth * Delay) should act as a constraint rather than (1+(2 * Bandwidth * Delay))?